# how to remove all space around a text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes

I need sans serif text inside nodes to be "perfectly" left aligned in a `tikzpicture` environment.

This code illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\author{Jander Moreira}
\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {
        inner sep = 0,
        outer sep = 0,
        anchor = west,
        align = left,
        draw,
    }]
    \foreach \t [count = \i] in {ORI, sem, HOJE, JM, ---, not}
        \node at (0, -0.5 * \i) {\t};
    \draw[ultra thin, blue] (0, -3.5) -- (0, 0);
    \draw[ultra thin, red] (0.025, -3.5) -- (0.025, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By setting `inner sep` and `outer sep` to zero removes the space (margins, padding) around the text, but the font itself has some space around each character.

The thin vertical lines and the node borders are only used for visual reference. Note that the nodes are left aligned (blue line), but the text is not (red line). The space before the "O" is larger than before the "s" and narrower than before the "H". There is no space before the dash (`---`).

My question: is there a way to remove the space before (and after) some text, so every first letter really touches the left border of a node?

Boxing text (`mbox`, for example) makes no difference.

Comment: @AndréC, I think `H` still is not aligned like wished.

Comment: This isn't really a TikZ question. PGF just puts the node contents in a box and puts that box whereever you place the node. Doing `\fboxsep=0pt\foreach \t [count = \i] in {ORI, sem, HOJE, JM, ---, not}{\fbox{\t}\par}` (outside of TikZ) shows you almost the same output.