# Align sans-serif text with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, alignment

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt, draw, very thin, rectangle] (a) at (0,0) {\scalebox{15}{\sffamily LARGE}};

\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt, draw, very thin, rectangle] (b) at (0,-4) {\scalebox{3}{\sffamily smaller text}};

\draw[blue] (a.west) ++ (0,-2cm) -- ++(0,4cm);
\draw[red] (a.west) ++ (-0.2cm,0) -- ++(0.4cm,0);
\draw[red] (a.west) ++ (0,-0.2cm) -- ++(0,0.4cm);

\draw[blue] (b.west) ++ (0,-2cm) -- ++(0,4cm);
\draw[red] (b.west) ++ (-0.2cm,0) -- ++(0.4cm,0);
\draw[red] (b.west) ++ (0,-0.2cm) -- ++(0,0.4cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this result:

[image: result of MWE]

Why is there some space between the "bounding box" and the letter L? I want to remove the white space around the text exactly, such that the vertical line of the L and the smaller text below align perfectly.

Further, I want to scale the smaller text such that it becomes exactly as wide as the top text. How is that possible?

Comment: duplicate -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504878/how-to-remove-all-space-around-a-text

Comment: indeed. but not very helpful, though :-(

Comment: Add xsep=0? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95655

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with tikz. tikz can only use the font metrics, it doesn't see the ink and the letters do have side bearings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\fontsize{1cm}{1.3cm}\selectfont \sffamily
LARGE

TEST

XXX

\tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(0,5);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are only viewing it as a problem because you are trying to use the letter as a graphic, in running text you actually expect letters to have side bearings and not to touch each other.